# How to concatenate two strings in H2O

Tags: concatenation, paste, h2o

I have a H2O frame in R with two character columns and I would like to create a new column by concatenating them. I tried the following but it failed as Paste function is not supported by H2O. Any other ideas? I searched for a solution but haven't found one so far. Thank you.

df$Col3 = paste(df$Col1, df$Col2)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the `h2o.interaction` function.  It's not as simple as a `paste` function and I don't think you can choose the concatenation separator (it uses `_`), but it may work for your purposes.  Here is a brief example.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

h2oframe <- as.h2o(Titanic)
h2oframe$Col3 <- h2o.interaction(h2oframe,
                                 factors = list(c("Sex", "Age")),
                                 pairwise = T,
                                 max_factors = 100000,
                                 min_occurrence = 1)
head(h2oframe)
  Class    Sex   Age Survived Freq         Col3
  1   1st   Male Child       No    0   Male_Child
  2   2nd   Male Child       No    0   Male_Child
  3   3rd   Male Child       No   35   Male_Child
  4  Crew   Male Child       No    0   Male_Child
  5   1st Female Child       No    0 Female_Child
  6   2nd Female Child       No    0 Female_Child
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. This is probably the only way, I guess. I explored options over the last 2 days but couldn't find one. I have been trying to not convert a h2o frame to R data frame for data processing. But after realizing that h2o has limited support functions, I have to decided to do all necessary processing with data tables and then convert necessary data to h2o prior to model execution.